# Css 'div overflow '- When I run the scroll, the divs follow the motion

Tags: css, html, position, alignment, overflow

I developed the following interface :

[image: Before Scroll]

Everything seems to be okay ... but when we roll our scroll bar, we have the following situation:

[image: After Scroll]

The names of the "users" of the chat, accompanying scroll, being styled with fixed position `position:absolute;`.
I tried some fixes but to no avail! you guys can see the problem this  jsFiddle [**Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/jDXCn/5/)

```
li > span.frdName {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:'Verdana', cursive;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    margin-right:200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Could someone give me a force with that? Or a better way to do?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jDXCn/11/ ?

Comment: Thanks friend apparently works! You could spend what you changed in the code? Once you pass this problem can solve it! Thank you!

Comment: You just put it right? `#navlist li {...position:relative;}` - Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey friend, I no have reputation this.

Comment: @Passerby, Post that as an answer so you can get credit for fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, `li > span.frdName` has `position:absolute`, so it will be absolutely positioned related to its ["positioned parent"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent);

And because the nearest parent that has `position` style is `div#chat-master`, `span.frdName` will positioned related to it.

To solve this, you can add a `position` style to the `li`:

```css
#navlist li {
    /*
     * ......
     * original style
     */
    position:relative;
}
```

[Fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jDXCn/11/)

Now the `span` will be positioned according to `li`, thus scroll with it.